# textview.setText isn't working in my code

Tags: java, android

All the `setText` methods below are not working. I could not understand why.
Can anyone help?

```
//imports

 public class Main2Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

RadioButton rb1;
RadioButton rb2;
RadioButton rb3;
RadioButton rb4;
TextView P1Name;
TextView P2Name;
TextView P3Name;
TextView P4Name;



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    rb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
    rb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
    rb4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.radioButton1) {
            rb2.setChecked(false);
            rb3.setChecked(false);
            rb4.setChecked(false);
        }
        if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.radioButton2) {
            rb1.setChecked(false);
            rb3.setChecked(false);
            rb4.setChecked(false);
        }
        if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.radioButton3) {
            rb1.setChecked(false);
            rb2.setChecked(false);
            rb4.setChecked(false);
        }
        if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.radioButton4) {
            rb1.setChecked(false);
            rb2.setChecked(false);
            rb3.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        P1Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlayerName1);
        P2Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlayerName2);
        P3Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlayerName3);
        P4Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlayerName4);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String P1 = intent.getStringExtra("Player1Name");
        String P2 = intent.getStringExtra("Player2Name");
        String P3 = intent.getStringExtra("Player3Name");
        String P4 = intent.getStringExtra("Player4Name");

        P1Name.setText("hello");
        Log.d("string content: ", P1Name.getText() + " <---- ");
        P2Name.setText("working");
        Log.d("string content: ", P2Name.getText() + " <---- ");
        P3Name.setText(P3.toString());
        Log.d("string content: ", P3Name.getText() + " <---- ");
        P4Name.setText(P4);


    }
}
```

Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="katerji.malek.score.Main2Activity2">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="85sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:hint="score" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="85sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:hint="score" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="85sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:hint="score" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="85sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:hint="score"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText4" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3"
    android:checked="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:text="\\/"
    android:layout_width="45sp" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:text="\\/"
    android:layout_width="45sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton2" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText" />

<Button
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:text="\\/"
    android:layout_width="45sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton3" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText5" />

<Button
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:text="\\/"
    android:layout_width="45sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton4"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton4" />

<Button
    android:text="Sajjil"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:text="New Game"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button8" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:text="Player 1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/PlayerName1"
            android:layout_width="85sp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Player2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/PlayerName2"
            android:layout_width="85sp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Player3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/PlayerName3"
            android:layout_width="85sp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Player4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/PlayerName4"
            android:layout_width="85sp"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Show activity_main2.xml layout too

Comment: where is your xml?

Comment: To provide dimensions you need to use "dp" and not "sp", sp it's only for Text sizes. And you have an extra empty TableRow at the end

Comment: Maybe your intent data is null. Put a check for the intent extras being null. Also, are you not able to see the text "hello" "working" for P1 and P2 (since they are simple setText() calls without intent data) ?

Comment: @MatPag Yes thank you Mat for the information. I'm still applying changes to the code but I ran into this specific problem. Do you have any thoughts about it?

Comment: @KunalChawla Yes the simple settext for P1 and P2 are also not showing for me. And the intent extras are working fine.

Comment: Okay. You can put a breakpoint on each of the setText method calls and see if the issue is in Java. Otherwise, see the runtime xml layout to see if the TextViews are visible or not. Your code is fine otherwise.

Comment: It turns out that the text is being set to the textView successfully. However it is still not showing on the layout. How can I fix that?

Comment: I tried this on my system. Got it to work.
The only difference was that I did not use intents, but simple static string values for P1, P2, P3 and P4.

As you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/9K5YGaI.png), the code is the same, and I am getting the values using setText.

Comment: To solve my problem I deleted the implements declaration "CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener" and the two methods 1) onCreateOptionsMenu and 2) onCheckedChanged and the settext worked perfectly. I didn't really know why but it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the implements declaration `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`
and the 2 methods: `nCreateOptionsMenu` and `onCheckedChanged`.
This is the working code:

```
public class Main2Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity  {

RadioButton rb1;
RadioButton rb2;
RadioButton rb3;
RadioButton rb4;
TextView P1Name;
TextView P2Name;
TextView P3Name;
TextView P4Name;



    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        P1Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlayerName1);
        P2Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlayerName2);
        P3Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlayerName3);
        P4Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlayerName4);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String P1 = intent.getStringExtra("Player1Name");
        String P2 = intent.getStringExtra("Player2Name");
        String P3 = intent.getStringExtra("Player3Name");
        String P4 = intent.getStringExtra("Player4Name");
        P1Name.setText(P1);
        P2Name.setText(P2);
        P3Name.setText(P3);
        P4Name.setText(P4);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try declaring your String variables with a toString on the end like below:

```
    P3Name.setText(P3.toString());
```